# What dictates the order of multiple integrity violations in mysql? If multiple columns are invalid, which integrity violation will be risen first?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

A table `sites` has two unique columns: `code` and `name`.

A record with `code` 'MIG000X1' and `name` 'MIG000X1 Some St. San Jose' already exists. Here's what happens when i try to insert a duplicate:

```
> insert into sites(account_id,division,code,name,is_active) values(1, 20, 'MIG000X1', 'MIG000X1 Some St. San Jose', 1);
(1062, "Duplicate entry 'MIG000X1 Some St. San Jose' for key 'name'")

> insert into sites(account_id,division,code,name,is_active) values(1, 20, 'MIG000X1', 'MIG000X1a Some St. San Jose', 1);
(1062, "Duplicate entry 'MIG000X1' for key 'code'")
```

In the example above, when both values are duplicate, constraint violation for column `name` is risen first. Why is that? What dictates this ordering?

[update]

```
> show create table sites;
+---------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table   | Create Table                                                                         |
|---------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| sites   | CREATE TABLE `sites` (                                                               |
|         |   `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,                                              |
|         |   `account_id` int(11) NOT NULL,                                                     |
|         |   `division` int(11) NOT NULL,                                                       |
|         |   `name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,                                                   |
|         |   `code` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,                                                   |
|         |   `phone` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,                                                  |
|         |   `fax` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,                                                    |
|         |   `street` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,                                                |
|         |   `city` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,                                                   |
|         |   `state` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,                                                   |
|         |   `zip` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,                                                    |
|         |   `floor_footage` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,                                              |
|         |   `is_active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,                                                   |
|         |   `email` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,                                                  |
|         |   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),                                                                |
|         |   UNIQUE KEY `fax` (`fax`),                                                          |
|         |   UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`),                                                        |
|         |   UNIQUE KEY `code` (`code`),                                                        |
|         |   UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`),                                                      |
|         |   UNIQUE KEY `email_2` (`email`),                                                    |
|         |   KEY `account_id` (`account_id`),                                                   |
|         |   CONSTRAINT `sites_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`account_id`) REFERENCES `accounts` (`id`), |
|         |   CONSTRAINT `CONSTRAINT_2` CHECK (`is_active` in (0,1))                             |
|         | ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4135 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1                           |
+---------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

1 row in set
Time: 0.013s
> show index from sites;
+---------+--------------+------------+----------------+---------------+-------------+---------------+------------+----------+--------+--------------+-----------+-----------------+
| Table   | Non_unique   | Key_name   | Seq_in_index   | Column_name   | Collation   | Cardinality   | Sub_part   | Packed   | Null   | Index_type   | Comment   | Index_comment   |
|---------+--------------+------------+----------------+---------------+-------------+---------------+------------+----------+--------+--------------+-----------+-----------------|
| sites   | 0            | PRIMARY    | 1              | id            | A           | 2364          | <null>     | <null>   |        | BTREE        |           |                 |
| sites   | 0            | fax        | 1              | fax           | A           | 2             | <null>     | <null>   | YES    | BTREE        |           |                 |
| sites   | 0            | name       | 1              | name          | A           | 2364          | <null>     | <null>   | YES    | BTREE        |           |                 |
| sites   | 0            | code       | 1              | code          | A           | 2364          | <null>     | <null>   | YES    | BTREE        |           |                 |
| sites   | 0            | email      | 1              | email         | A           | 2             | <null>     | <null>   | YES    | BTREE        |           |                 |
| sites   | 0            | email_2    | 1              | email         | A           | 2             | <null>     | <null>   | YES    | BTREE        |           |                 |
| sites   | 1            | account_id | 1              | account_id    | A           | 14            | <null>     | <null>   |        | BTREE        |           |                 |
+---------+--------------+------------+----------------+---------------+-------------+---------------+------------+----------+--------+--------------+-----------+-----------------+
```

Comment: This is not documented. Show complete outputs for `SHOW CREATE TABLE sites;` and `SHOW INDEX FROM sites;`.

Comment: Look - the index by `name` is listed above the index by `code` in both outputs. Try to swap them in table structure - does this will alter "preferred" check?

Comment: @Akina Interesting observation. I tried what you suggested, and i can see the pattern - which ever index is created first, fires first. It wasn't as obvious before, as i was generating my schema using SQLAlchemy. I'll have to do more testing, to see if this true indeed, and there are no other factors / side effects.

Comment: @Akina Thanks for pointing me to the right path!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading, and re-reading documentation, i have stumbled upon the answer -

[`Before a row is inserted or updated, all constraints are evaluated in the order they are defined.`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/alter-table/#add-constraint) This goes along with what i observed during testing.